# Highchart StockChart - Update last point value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I'm trying to implement an ajax stockchart that needs to update every second but accumulate the total values per minute. Everything works fine when it detects new minutes values but when i try to update the last point value (last minute) I just can't get it because I'm getting console error saying that it doesn't recognize the properties.

```
aaa2.php:107 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
    at Object.success (aaa2.php:107)
    at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
```

and this is the portion code for updating the last point.

```
series[0].data[0].update(500);
```

This is the complete code I'm using to get some idea how to solve my problem or any shared solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        var ultima_fecha;
        var ultimo_tx100;
            Highcharts.setOptions({
             global: {
            useUTC: true
             }
        }); // end Highcharts.setOptions


$.ajax({
                url: "/proyectos/method/ajax_spline.php",
                type: 'get',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(DatosRecuperados) {
                var matrix=new Array();
                $.each(DatosRecuperados, function(i,o){

                    var my_utc=Date.UTC(parseInt(o.anio),parseInt(o.mes),parseInt(o.dia),parseInt(o.hora),parseInt(o.x));


                    if (o.x) {DatosRecuperados[i].x =parseInt(my_utc);}
                    if (o.y) {DatosRecuperados[i].y = parseFloat(o.y);}
                });

                set_fecha(DatosRecuperados[(DatosRecuperados.length)-1].x);
                set_tx100(DatosRecuperados[(DatosRecuperados.length)-1].y);
                //console.log(DatosRecuperados.length);

      var my_chart=$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            type:'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg,

          events: {
            load: function () {
                series = this.series[0];
            }
          }
        },plotOptions: {
            dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
            },
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        title: {
          text: 'Live random data'
        },

        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
          name: 'Random data',
          data: DatosRecuperados
        }]

      }); //end highchart
} //end success ajax


 }); //end ajax 

}); //end doc ready


setInterval(function () {

                $.get( "/proyectos/method/ajax_spline.php?Consultar=1", function( UltimosDatos ) {
                    var UltimosDatos=$.parseJSON(UltimosDatos);
                    //var varlocalx=parseFloat(UltimosDatos[0].x);
                    var varlocalx=Date.UTC(parseInt(UltimosDatos[0].anio),parseInt(UltimosDatos[0].mes),parseInt(UltimosDatos[0].dia),parseInt(UltimosDatos[0].hora),parseInt(UltimosDatos[0].x));
                    var varlocaly=parseFloat(UltimosDatos[0].y);
                 if((get_fecha()==parseInt(varlocalx))&&(get_tx100()!=varlocaly)){   
                    //console.log(varlocaly);
                        series[0].data[0].update(500);            

                    }
                 if((get_fecha()!=parseInt(varlocalx))&&(get_tx100()!=varlocaly)){

                    series.addPoint([parseInt(varlocalx), varlocaly], true, true);
                    set_fecha(varlocalx);
                    set_tx100(varlocaly);
                }
           });}, 1000);

  function get_fecha(){return ultima_fecha;}
   function set_fecha(x){ ultima_fecha=x;}

   function get_tx100(){return ultimo_tx100;}
   function set_tx100(y){ ultimo_tx100=y;} 

</script>
```

Comment: Hi user2570870, Please try to disable `dataGrouping`: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.enabled

Comment: do you have any sample about how to disable it?

Comment: Yes, of course: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tfo15cj9/

Comment: I've update my code (take a look upside) and i do even get the same result (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create reference to the first chart series in global variable `series`:

`series = this.series[0];`

So, you should update the first point in this way:

```
 setInterval(function() {
     series.points[0].update({
         y: Math.random() * 1000
     });
 }, 1000);
```

To disable `dataGrouping` correctly:

```
         plotOptions: {
             series: {
                 dataGrouping: {
                     enabled: false
                 },
             },

             spline: {
                 ...
             }
         }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/2091/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled

Comment: THank you for your answer, seems my problem was i wasnt disabling corretly dataGrouping, however i'm not able to update just the last point value.

Comment: @user2570870, Please analyze this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/2134/ - there is a very similar situation to yours.

Comment: It's a very good sample and it worked like a shum. By the way, when i start running my chart and for example my ajax (every second) returns value since 09am and now its 14.06, the whole data dissapears and i only get the last 8 minutes information. I have to refresh the site to see the historical info, are there any way to do not loose info instead refreshing the page?

Comment: @user2570870, I do not know what is your current code, but if you use `update` method only on some specific data point, than your chart should work similar like in my example.

Comment: dear ppotaczek, my actual code is the one is updated in my question, actually my problem was solved according your suggestion but now seems like im loosing data from navigator, i just keep the last 8 minutes even when i have more information older than 12 hours.

Comment: @user2570870, It is very hard to point out the problem without looking at the result of your code. It would be best if you reproduce your problem on jsfiddle. Eventually, you can try to disable `dataGrouping` in `navigator`: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.series.dataGrouping.enabled or `ordinal` in `xAxis`: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: Dear ppotaczec, here i attach an idea https://prnt.sc/mea4vr , in that image u could see i'm just keeping data from 12 to 17pm, but in real life ive seen information from 04am until 17pm, if i refresh the site i can see the whole information. The only one thing ive changed is the code you recomended me for update last point and datagrouping. Please some help.

Comment: Hi user2570870, Yes, I see the problem but without live example I do not know what causes it and I am unable to help you.

Comment: Not sure how to make it online because when i ran my sample it starts from 00.00 and every second is updating the information per minute, so after half hour and even more (12 hours),  i only have the last 8 minutes and not the whole data. To get the whole data i need to refresh my site and thats what i dont want. My problem is similar to this sample http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/zJZSx/. As u can see it shows just some information and making comparison with mine, mine has navigator

Comment: Yes, because you set the `shift` argument in `addPoint` method: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint to true. Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d729shv8/

Comment: wow @ppotaczek, its amazin, just to make a last question. Is it possible you could share your last jsfiddle example but using more than 1 serie (2 or 3 lines). ?